# Difference between EOS transaction "traces" and "trx"

Tags: transactions, rpc

I use RPC to retrieve transaction information - e.g:

```
{
  "id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
  "trx": {
    "receipt": {
      "status": "executed",
      "cpu_usage_us": 1848,
      "net_usage_words": 17,
      "trx": [
        1,
        {
          "signatures": [
            "SIG_K1_K4gHC6u9Pz9bR18roHt6urZv8vXeCy9i3XbRQvSuzxdPfNsXFQyog15cqRBFUUn7Q5Vacifi53xzMttFKs3K29KRkKgL7M"
          ],
          "compression": "none",
          "packed_context_free_data": "",
          "packed_trx": "f4dd085da0cc21bc802f000000000100a6823403ea3055000000572d3ccdcd0120029b3439dda67b00000000a8ed32322520029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a3100"
        }
      ]
    },
    "trx": {
      "expiration": "2019-06-18T12:49:56",
      "ref_block_num": 52384,
      "ref_block_prefix": 796965921,
      "max_net_usage_words": 0,
      "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
      "delay_sec": 0,
      "context_free_actions": [],
      "actions": [
        {
          "account": "eosio.token",
          "name": "transfer",
          "authorization": [
            {
              "actor": "jinhuidong12",
              "permission": "active"
            }
          ],
          "data": {
            "from": "jinhuidong12",
            "to": "eossanguoone",
            "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
            "memo": "mw:1"
          },
          "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
        }
      ],
      "transaction_extensions": [],
      "signatures": [
        "SIG_K1_K4gHC6u9Pz9bR18roHt6urZv8vXeCy9i3XbRQvSuzxdPfNsXFQyog15cqRBFUUn7Q5Vacifi53xzMttFKs3K29KRkKgL7M"
      ],
      "context_free_data": []
    }
  },
  "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
  "block_num": 64146925,
  "last_irreversible_block": 64150104,
  "traces": [
    {
      "receipt": {
        "receiver": "eosio.token",
        "act_digest": "2da2811d95f4c5f02f8edb398b8117c425e3f561cac4606c49410721e49a00c1",
        "global_sequence": "7339493163",
        "recv_sequence": 1088370572,
        "auth_sequence": [
          [
            "jinhuidong12",
            2234
          ]
        ],
        "code_sequence": 3,
        "abi_sequence": 3
      },
      "act": {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "jinhuidong12",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "jinhuidong12",
          "to": "eossanguoone",
          "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
          "memo": "mw:1"
        },
        "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
      },
      "context_free": false,
      "elapsed": 77,
      "console": "",
      "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
      "block_num": 64146925,
      "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
      "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
      "account_ram_deltas": [],
      "except": null,
      "inline_traces": [
        {
          "receipt": {
            "receiver": "jinhuidong12",
            "act_digest": "2da2811d95f4c5f02f8edb398b8117c425e3f561cac4606c49410721e49a00c1",
            "global_sequence": "7339493164",
            "recv_sequence": 527,
            "auth_sequence": [
              [
                "jinhuidong12",
                2235
              ]
            ],
            "code_sequence": 3,
            "abi_sequence": 3
          },
          "act": {
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [
              {
                "actor": "jinhuidong12",
                "permission": "active"
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "from": "jinhuidong12",
              "to": "eossanguoone",
              "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
              "memo": "mw:1"
            },
            "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
          },
          "context_free": false,
          "elapsed": 4,
          "console": "",
          "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
          "block_num": 64146925,
          "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
          "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
          "account_ram_deltas": [],
          "except": null,
          "inline_traces": []
        },
        {
          "receipt": {
            "receiver": "eossanguoone",
            "act_digest": "2da2811d95f4c5f02f8edb398b8117c425e3f561cac4606c49410721e49a00c1",
            "global_sequence": "7339493165",
            "recv_sequence": 4484708,
            "auth_sequence": [
              [
                "jinhuidong12",
                2236
              ]
            ],
            "code_sequence": 3,
            "abi_sequence": 3
          },
          "act": {
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [
              {
                "actor": "jinhuidong12",
                "permission": "active"
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "from": "jinhuidong12",
              "to": "eossanguoone",
              "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
              "memo": "mw:1"
            },
            "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
          },
          "context_free": false,
          "elapsed": 445,
          "console": "",
          "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
          "block_num": 64146925,
          "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
          "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
          "account_ram_deltas": [],
          "except": null,
          "inline_traces": []
        },
        {
          "receipt": {
            "receiver": "eosio.token",
            "act_digest": "65d563086a26cc07cf444f567a0584b7400291d7496183e4ee3c66dc85bcb794",
            "global_sequence": "7339493166",
            "recv_sequence": 1088370573,
            "auth_sequence": [
              [
                "eossanguoone",
                1421814
              ]
            ],
            "code_sequence": 3,
            "abi_sequence": 3
          },
          "act": {
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [
              {
                "actor": "eossanguoone",
                "permission": "active"
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "from": "eossanguoone",
              "to": "eossanguodiv",
              "quantity": "0.0400 EOS",
              "memo": "EOS Dynasty dividend pool"
            },
            "hex_data": "a026a59a4d833155b05da29a4d833155900100000000000004454f530000000019454f532044796e61737479206469766964656e6420706f6f6c"
          },
          "context_free": false,
          "elapsed": 51,
          "console": "",
          "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
          "block_num": 64146925,
          "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
          "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
          "account_ram_deltas": [],
          "except": null,
          "inline_traces": [
            {
              "receipt": {
                "receiver": "eossanguoone",
                "act_digest": "65d563086a26cc07cf444f567a0584b7400291d7496183e4ee3c66dc85bcb794",
                "global_sequence": "7339493167",
                "recv_sequence": 4484709,
                "auth_sequence": [
                  [
                    "eossanguoone",
                    1421815
                  ]
                ],
                "code_sequence": 3,
                "abi_sequence": 3
              },
              "act": {
                "account": "eosio.token",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [
                  {
                    "actor": "eossanguoone",
                    "permission": "active"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "from": "eossanguoone",
                  "to": "eossanguodiv",
                  "quantity": "0.0400 EOS",
                  "memo": "EOS Dynasty dividend pool"
                },
                "hex_data": "a026a59a4d833155b05da29a4d833155900100000000000004454f530000000019454f532044796e61737479206469766964656e6420706f6f6c"
              },
              "context_free": false,
              "elapsed": 129,
              "console": "",
              "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
              "block_num": 64146925,
              "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
              "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
              "account_ram_deltas": [],
              "except": null,
              "inline_traces": []
            },
            {
              "receipt": {
                "receiver": "eossanguodiv",
                "act_digest": "65d563086a26cc07cf444f567a0584b7400291d7496183e4ee3c66dc85bcb794",
                "global_sequence": "7339493168",
                "recv_sequence": 60622,
                "auth_sequence": [
                  [
                    "eossanguoone",
                    1421816
                  ]
                ],
                "code_sequence": 3,
                "abi_sequence": 3
              },
              "act": {
                "account": "eosio.token",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [
                  {
                    "actor": "eossanguoone",
                    "permission": "active"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "from": "eossanguoone",
                  "to": "eossanguodiv",
                  "quantity": "0.0400 EOS",
                  "memo": "EOS Dynasty dividend pool"
                },
                "hex_data": "a026a59a4d833155b05da29a4d833155900100000000000004454f530000000019454f532044796e61737479206469766964656e6420706f6f6c"
              },
              "context_free": false,
              "elapsed": 5,
              "console": "",
              "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
              "block_num": 64146925,
              "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
              "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
              "account_ram_deltas": [],
              "except": null,
              "inline_traces": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "receipt": {
            "receiver": "eossanguotkt",
            "act_digest": "5dd1f0b7cff775473effca33796d11bce5f1db77a0bf5229fc2ae175ef2e9de9",
            "global_sequence": "7339493169",
            "recv_sequence": 1037457,
            "auth_sequence": [
              [
                "eossanguotkt",
                1106624
              ]
            ],
            "code_sequence": 4,
            "abi_sequence": 1
          },
          "act": {
            "account": "eossanguotkt",
            "name": "issue",
            "authorization": [
              {
                "actor": "eossanguotkt",
                "permission": "issue"
              }
            ],
            "data": {
              "to": "jinhuidong12",
              "quantity": "200.0000 TKT",
              "memo": "TKT airdrop!"
            },
            "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67b80841e000000000004544b54000000000c544b542061697264726f7021"
          },
          "context_free": false,
          "elapsed": 115,
          "console": "",
          "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
          "block_num": 64146925,
          "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
          "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
          "account_ram_deltas": [
            {
              "account": "eossanguotkt",
              "delta": 240
            }
          ],
          "except": null,
          "inline_traces": [
            {
              "receipt": {
                "receiver": "eossanguotkt",
                "act_digest": "e6c01181b693413758095c8729da51ffd81fe8c564e8708d92b4bb5f4fa4bd7e",
                "global_sequence": "7339493170",
                "recv_sequence": 1037458,
                "auth_sequence": [
                  [
                    "eossanguotkt",
                    1106625
                  ]
                ],
                "code_sequence": 4,
                "abi_sequence": 1
              },
              "act": {
                "account": "eossanguotkt",
                "name": "transfer",
                "authorization": [
                  {
                    "actor": "eossanguotkt",
                    "permission": "active"
                  }
                ],
                "data": {
                  "from": "eossanguotkt",
                  "to": "jinhuidong12",
                  "quantity": "200.0000 TKT",
                  "memo": "TKT airdrop!"
                },
                "hex_data": "9061a69a4d83315520029b3439dda67b80841e000000000004544b54000000000c544b542061697264726f7021"
              },
              "context_free": false,
              "elapsed": 82,
              "console": "",
              "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
              "block_num": 64146925,
              "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
              "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
              "account_ram_deltas": [
                {
                  "account": "eossanguotkt",
                  "delta": -240
                }
              ],
              "except": null,
              "inline_traces": [
                {
                  "receipt": {
                    "receiver": "jinhuidong12",
                    "act_digest": "e6c01181b693413758095c8729da51ffd81fe8c564e8708d92b4bb5f4fa4bd7e",
                    "global_sequence": "7339493171",
                    "recv_sequence": 528,
                    "auth_sequence": [
                      [
                        "eossanguotkt",
                        1106626
                      ]
                    ],
                    "code_sequence": 4,
                    "abi_sequence": 1
                  },
                  "act": {
                    "account": "eossanguotkt",
                    "name": "transfer",
                    "authorization": [
                      {
                        "actor": "eossanguotkt",
                        "permission": "active"
                      }
                    ],
                    "data": {
                      "from": "eossanguotkt",
                      "to": "jinhuidong12",
                      "quantity": "200.0000 TKT",
                      "memo": "TKT airdrop!"
                    },
                    "hex_data": "9061a69a4d83315520029b3439dda67b80841e000000000004544b54000000000c544b542061697264726f7021"
                  },
                  "context_free": false,
                  "elapsed": 3,
                  "console": "",
                  "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
                  "block_num": 64146925,
                  "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
                  "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
                  "account_ram_deltas": [],
                  "except": null,
                  "inline_traces": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "receipt": {
        "receiver": "jinhuidong12",
        "act_digest": "2da2811d95f4c5f02f8edb398b8117c425e3f561cac4606c49410721e49a00c1",
        "global_sequence": "7339493164",
        "recv_sequence": 527,
        "auth_sequence": [
          [
            "jinhuidong12",
            2235
          ]
        ],
        "code_sequence": 3,
        "abi_sequence": 3
      },
      "act": {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "jinhuidong12",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "jinhuidong12",
          "to": "eossanguoone",
          "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
          "memo": "mw:1"
        },
        "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
      },
      "context_free": false,
      "elapsed": 4,
      "console": "",
      "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
      "block_num": 64146925,
      "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
      "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
      "account_ram_deltas": [],
      "except": null,
      "inline_traces": []
    },
    {
      "receipt": {
        "receiver": "eossanguoone",
        "act_digest": "2da2811d95f4c5f02f8edb398b8117c425e3f561cac4606c49410721e49a00c1",
        "global_sequence": "7339493165",
        "recv_sequence": 4484708,
        "auth_sequence": [
          [
            "jinhuidong12",
            2236
          ]
        ],
        "code_sequence": 3,
        "abi_sequence": 3
      },
      "act": {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "jinhuidong12",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "jinhuidong12",
          "to": "eossanguoone",
          "quantity": "0.2000 EOS",
          "memo": "mw:1"
        },
        "hex_data": "20029b3439dda67ba026a59a4d833155d00700000000000004454f5300000000046d773a31"
      },
      "context_free": false,
      "elapsed": 445,
      "console": "",
      "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
      "block_num": 64146925,
      "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
      "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
      "account_ram_deltas": [],
      "except": null,
      "inline_traces": []
    },
    {
      "receipt": {
        "receiver": "eossanguodiv",
        "act_digest": "65d563086a26cc07cf444f567a0584b7400291d7496183e4ee3c66dc85bcb794",
        "global_sequence": "7339493168",
        "recv_sequence": 60622,
        "auth_sequence": [
          [
            "eossanguoone",
            1421816
          ]
        ],
        "code_sequence": 3,
        "abi_sequence": 3
      },
      "act": {
        "account": "eosio.token",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "eossanguoone",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "eossanguoone",
          "to": "eossanguodiv",
          "quantity": "0.0400 EOS",
          "memo": "EOS Dynasty dividend pool"
        },
        "hex_data": "a026a59a4d833155b05da29a4d833155900100000000000004454f530000000019454f532044796e61737479206469766964656e6420706f6f6c"
      },
      "context_free": false,
      "elapsed": 5,
      "console": "",
      "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
      "block_num": 64146925,
      "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
      "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
      "account_ram_deltas": [],
      "except": null,
      "inline_traces": []
    },
    {
      "receipt": {
        "receiver": "jinhuidong12",
        "act_digest": "e6c01181b693413758095c8729da51ffd81fe8c564e8708d92b4bb5f4fa4bd7e",
        "global_sequence": "7339493171",
        "recv_sequence": 528,
        "auth_sequence": [
          [
            "eossanguotkt",
            1106626
          ]
        ],
        "code_sequence": 4,
        "abi_sequence": 1
      },
      "act": {
        "account": "eossanguotkt",
        "name": "transfer",
        "authorization": [
          {
            "actor": "eossanguotkt",
            "permission": "active"
          }
        ],
        "data": {
          "from": "eossanguotkt",
          "to": "jinhuidong12",
          "quantity": "200.0000 TKT",
          "memo": "TKT airdrop!"
        },
        "hex_data": "9061a69a4d83315520029b3439dda67b80841e000000000004544b54000000000c544b542061697264726f7021"
      },
      "context_free": false,
      "elapsed": 3,
      "console": "",
      "trx_id": "84373c7756f0ad09972cd839c4b862328aa96b40ea52b3e91633acf583dffe44",
      "block_num": 64146925,
      "block_time": "2019-06-18T12:44:58.000",
      "producer_block_id": "03d2cdede7c60ed03833ed1ca0d186400d7d389c54acf398c1030a6508b6aa26",
      "account_ram_deltas": [],
      "except": null,
      "inline_traces": []
    }
  ]
}
```

What's the difference between traces and trx.trx? It's not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

A trx contains a list of actions that were submitted to the blockchain along with the execution status. A trace shows each inline action called by the actions from the trx. There are other differences too, but I don't know what they are and I leave that for someone else to answer/edit this answer.